# javascript内の個々の要素に色を付ける方法

Tags: javascript

下記のコードは、アナログ時計の周囲に1分ごとに"和暦"と"西暦”を表示させ、その和暦の"平成"のみに
赤色を設定しようと試みたものですが、うまくいきません。以前も同じ質問をしたのですが、コードが
似て非なるものなので、よく分かりません。どうすれば、特定の文字に色を付けることができるでしょうか。

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        body {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.Face {
  position: absolute;
  height: 10;
  widdth: 10;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #0000ff;
}

.Hours {
  position: absolute;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.Minutes {
  position: absolute;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.Seconds {
  position: absolute;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #ff0000;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.Date {
  position: absolute;
  height: 10;
  width: 10;
  font-size: 1em;
  color:;
}
    </style>
    <script src="/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.min.js?v=1"></script>
    </head>
<body>
    <div id="clock">
    <div id="Od" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Of" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Oh" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Om" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Os" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

(function(){
        "use strict";

function $(sel) {
  return document.getElementById(sel);
}

function $$(sel) {
  return document.getElementsByClassName(sel);
}

function setPosition(element, y, x) {
  element.style.top = y + 'px';
  element.style.left = x + 'px';
}

const CLOCK_HEIGHT = 40,
    CLOCK_WIDTH = 40,
    CLOCK_FROM_MOUSE_Y = 0,
    CLOCK_FROM_MOUSE_X = 100;

const H = '...'.split('');
const M = '....'.split('');
const S = '.....'.split('');
const SPEED = 0.6,
    FACES = '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12'.split(' ');
const HAND_HEIGHT = CLOCK_HEIGHT / 4.5; 
const HAND_WIDTH = CLOCK_WIDTH / 4.5;
const HAND_Y = -7,
    HAND_X = -2.5,
    STEP = 0.06;

var ymouse = 0,
    xmouse = 0;
var currStep = 0;
var lastBasePositions = [];

function initialize() {
  for (var i = 0; i < FACES.length; ++i) {
    lastBasePositions[i] = {x:0, y:0};
  }

  var html = '';
  // Face wrapper
  html = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < FACES.length; ++i) {
    html += '<div class="Face">' + FACES[i] + '</div>';
  }
  $('Of').children[0].innerHTML = html;

  // Hours wrapper
  html = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < H.length; ++i) {
    html += '<div class="Hours">' + H[i] + '</div>';
  } 
  $('Oh').children[0].innerHTML = html;

  // Minute wrapper
  html = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < M.length; ++i) {
    html += '<div class="Minutes">' + M[i] + '</div>';
  }
  $('Om').children[0].innerHTML = html;

  // Seconds wrapper
  html = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < S.length; ++i) {
    html += '<div class="Seconds">' + S[i] + '</div>';
  }
  $('Os').children[0].innerHTML = html;

  // Mouse move event handler
  document.onmousemove = function(evnt) {
    ymouse = evnt.clientY + CLOCK_FROM_MOUSE_Y;
    xmouse = evnt.clientX + CLOCK_FROM_MOUSE_X;
  };

  requestAnimationFrame(ClockAndAssign);
}

var lastYearPositions = [{x:0, y:0}];
var lastYearString = ' ';
var lastYearLocale = '';
function updateYear(currentDate, scrll) {
  var yearString = lastYearString;
  if (currentDate.getMinutes() % 2 == 0) {
    if (lastYearLocale != 'ja'){
      yearString = currentDate.toLocaleDateString("ja-JP-u-ca-japanese", { era: "long", year: "numeric" }).
          replace(/\u200e/g, "").replace(" ", "");
    lastYearLocale = 'ja';
          }
  } else {
    if (lastYearLocale != 'en'){
      yearString = currentDate.toLocaleDateString("en-US", { era: "long", year: "numeric" }).
          replace(/\u200e/g, "") + "年";
    lastYearLocale = 'en';
          }
  }

  var yearLength = lastYearPositions.length;
  if (yearString != lastYearString) {
    lastYearString = yearString;        
    var yearCharacters = yearString.split('');
    yearLength = yearCharacters.length;

    // Date wrapper
    var html = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < yearLength; ++i) {
      html += '<div class="Date">' + yearCharacters[i] + '</div>';
    }
    $('Od').children[0].innerHTML = html;


  if ( currentDate.getMinutes() % 2 == 0 ) {

      var divChildren = $('Od').children[0].children;
         for (var i = 0; i < divChildren; ++i) {
            var divEl = divChildren[i];

      if ((i >= 0) && (i < 2)) {
            divEl.children[0].style.color="red";

                         }
                  }
          }

  }
  var positions = [{}];
  var lastPosition = lastYearPositions[0];
  positions[0].y = lastPosition.y + ((ymouse) - lastPosition.y) * SPEED;
  positions[0].x = lastPosition.x + ((xmouse) - lastPosition.x) * SPEED;
  for (var i = 1; i < yearLength; ++i) {
    lastPosition = i < lastYearPositions.length ?
        lastYearPositions[i] :
        lastYearPositions[lastYearPositions.length - 1];
    positions[i] = {};
    positions[i].y = lastPosition.y + (positions[i-1].y - lastPosition.y) * SPEED;
    positions[i].x = lastPosition.x + (positions[i-1].x - lastPosition.x) * SPEED;
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < yearLength; ++i) {
    var radian = currStep + i * (360 / yearLength) * Math.PI / 180;
    setPosition($$('Date')[i],
                Math.round(positions[i].y) + CLOCK_HEIGHT * 1.5 * Math.sin(radian) + scrll,
                Math.round(positions[i].x) + CLOCK_WIDTH * 1.5 * Math.cos(radian));
  }
  lastYearPositions = positions;
  currStep -= STEP;
}

function ClockAndAssign() {
  var date = new Date();
  var secs = date.getSeconds();
  var sec = -1.57 + Math.PI * secs / 30;
  var mins = date.getMinutes();
  var min = -1.57 + Math.PI * mins / 30;
  var hr = date.getHours();
  var hrs = -1.575 + Math.PI * hr / 6 + Math.PI * parseInt(date.getMinutes(), 10) / 360;
  $('Od').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
  $('Of').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
  $('Oh').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
  $('Om').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
  $('Os').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
  var scrll = 0;

  var positions = [{}];
  var lastPosition = lastBasePositions[0];
  positions[0].y = Math.round(lastPosition.y + (ymouse - lastPosition.y) * SPEED);
  positions[0].x = Math.round(lastPosition.x + (xmouse - lastPosition.x) * SPEED);
  for (var i = 1; i < FACES.length; ++i) {
    lastPosition = lastBasePositions[i];
    positions[i] = {};
    positions[i].y = Math.round(lastPosition.y + (positions[i - 1].y - lastPosition.y) * SPEED);
    positions[i].x = Math.round(lastPosition.x + (positions[i - 1].x - lastPosition.x) * SPEED);
  }
  lastBasePositions = positions;

  var split = 360 / FACES.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < FACES.length; ++i) {
    var radian = -1.0471 + i * split * Math.PI / 180;
    setPosition($$('Face')[i],
                positions[i].y + CLOCK_HEIGHT * Math.sin(radian) + scrll,
                positions[i].x + CLOCK_WIDTH * Math.cos(radian));
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < H.length; ++i) {
    setPosition($$('Hours')[i],
                positions[i].y + HAND_Y + (i * HAND_HEIGHT) * Math.sin(hrs) + scrll,
                positions[i].x + HAND_X + (i * HAND_WIDTH) * Math.cos(hrs));
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < M.length; ++i) {
    setPosition($$('Minutes')[i],
                positions[i].y + HAND_Y + (i * HAND_HEIGHT) * Math.sin(min) + scrll,
                positions[i].x + HAND_X + (i * HAND_WIDTH) * Math.cos(min));
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < S.length; ++i) {
    setPosition($$('Seconds')[i],
                positions[i].y + HAND_Y + (i * HAND_HEIGHT) * Math.sin(sec) + scrll,
                positions[i].x + HAND_X + (i * HAND_WIDTH) * Math.cos(sec));
  }
  updateYear(date, scrll);
  requestAnimationFrame(ClockAndAssign);
}

initialize();
}());
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
(function(){
        "use strict";

function $(sel) {
  return document.getElementById(sel);
}

function $$(sel) {
  return document.getElementsByClassName(sel);
}

function setPosition(element, y, x) {
  element.style.top = y + 'px';
  element.style.left = x + 'px';
}

const CLOCK_HEIGHT = 40,
    CLOCK_WIDTH = 40,
    CLOCK_FROM_MOUSE_Y = 0,
    CLOCK_FROM_MOUSE_X = 100;

const H = '...'.split('');
const M = '....'.split('');
const S = '.....'.split('');
const SPEED = 0.6,
    FACES = '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12'.split(' ');
const HAND_HEIGHT = CLOCK_HEIGHT / 4.5; 
const HAND_WIDTH = CLOCK_WIDTH / 4.5;
const HAND_Y = -7,
    HAND_X = -2.5,
    STEP = 0.06;

var ymouse = 0,
    xmouse = 0;
var currStep = 0;
var lastBasePositions = [];

function initialize() {
  for (var i = 0; i < FACES.length; ++i) {
    lastBasePositions[i] = {x:0, y:0};
  }

  var html = '';
  // Face wrapper
  html = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < FACES.length; ++i) {
    html += '<div class="Face">' + FACES[i] + '</div>';
  }
  $('Of').children[0].innerHTML = html;

  // Hours wrapper
  html = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < H.length; ++i) {
    html += '<div class="Hours">' + H[i] + '</div>';
  } 
  $('Oh').children[0].innerHTML = html;

  // Minute wrapper
  html = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < M.length; ++i) {
    html += '<div class="Minutes">' + M[i] + '</div>';
  }
  $('Om').children[0].innerHTML = html;

  // Seconds wrapper
  html = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < S.length; ++i) {
    html += '<div class="Seconds">' + S[i] + '</div>';
  }
  $('Os').children[0].innerHTML = html;

  // Mouse move event handler
  document.onmousemove = function(evnt) {
    ymouse = evnt.clientY + CLOCK_FROM_MOUSE_Y;
    xmouse = evnt.clientX + CLOCK_FROM_MOUSE_X;
  };

  requestAnimationFrame(ClockAndAssign);
}

var lastYearPositions = [{x:0, y:0}];
var lastYearString = ' ';
var lastYearLocale = '';
function updateYear(currentDate, scrll) {
  var yearString = lastYearString;
  if (currentDate.getMinutes() % 2 == 0) {
    if (lastYearLocale != 'ja'){
      yearString = currentDate.toLocaleDateString("ja-JP-u-ca-japanese", { era: "long", year: "numeric" }).
          replace(/\u200e/g, "").replace(" ", "");
    lastYearLocale = 'ja';
          }
  } else {
    if (lastYearLocale != 'en'){
      yearString = currentDate.toLocaleDateString("en-US", { era: "long", year: "numeric" }).
          replace(/\u200e/g, "") + "年";
    lastYearLocale = 'en';
          }
  }

  var yearLength = lastYearPositions.length;
  if (yearString != lastYearString) {
    lastYearString = yearString;        
    var yearCharacters = yearString.split('');
    yearLength = yearCharacters.length;

    // Date wrapper
    var html = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < yearLength; ++i) {
      html += '<div class="Date">' + yearCharacters[i] + '</div>';
    }
    $('Od').children[0].innerHTML = html;


  if ( currentDate.getMinutes() % 2 == 0 ) {

      var divChildren = $('Od').children[0].children;
         for (var i = 0; i < divChildren; ++i) {
            var divEl = divChildren[i];
               
      if ((i >= 0) && (i < 2)) {
            divEl.children[0].style.color="red";
                              
                         }
                  }
          }

  }
  var positions = [{}];
  var lastPosition = lastYearPositions[0];
  positions[0].y = lastPosition.y + ((ymouse) - lastPosition.y) * SPEED;
  positions[0].x = lastPosition.x + ((xmouse) - lastPosition.x) * SPEED;
  for (var i = 1; i < yearLength; ++i) {
    lastPosition = i < lastYearPositions.length ?
        lastYearPositions[i] :
        lastYearPositions[lastYearPositions.length - 1];
    positions[i] = {};
    positions[i].y = lastPosition.y + (positions[i-1].y - lastPosition.y) * SPEED;
    positions[i].x = lastPosition.x + (positions[i-1].x - lastPosition.x) * SPEED;
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < yearLength; ++i) {
    var radian = currStep + i * (360 / yearLength) * Math.PI / 180;
    setPosition($$('Date')[i],
                Math.round(positions[i].y) + CLOCK_HEIGHT * 1.5 * Math.sin(radian) + scrll,
                Math.round(positions[i].x) + CLOCK_WIDTH * 1.5 * Math.cos(radian));
  }
  lastYearPositions = positions;
  currStep -= STEP;
}

function ClockAndAssign() {
  var date = new Date();
  var secs = date.getSeconds();
  var sec = -1.57 + Math.PI * secs / 30;
  var mins = date.getMinutes();
  var min = -1.57 + Math.PI * mins / 30;
  var hr = date.getHours();
  var hrs = -1.575 + Math.PI * hr / 6 + Math.PI * parseInt(date.getMinutes(), 10) / 360;
  $('Od').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
  $('Of').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
  $('Oh').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
  $('Om').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
  $('Os').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
  var scrll = 0;

  var positions = [{}];
  var lastPosition = lastBasePositions[0];
  positions[0].y = Math.round(lastPosition.y + (ymouse - lastPosition.y) * SPEED);
  positions[0].x = Math.round(lastPosition.x + (xmouse - lastPosition.x) * SPEED);
  for (var i = 1; i < FACES.length; ++i) {
    lastPosition = lastBasePositions[i];
    positions[i] = {};
    positions[i].y = Math.round(lastPosition.y + (positions[i - 1].y - lastPosition.y) * SPEED);
    positions[i].x = Math.round(lastPosition.x + (positions[i - 1].x - lastPosition.x) * SPEED);
  }
  lastBasePositions = positions;

  var split = 360 / FACES.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < FACES.length; ++i) {
    var radian = -1.0471 + i * split * Math.PI / 180;
    setPosition($$('Face')[i],
                positions[i].y + CLOCK_HEIGHT * Math.sin(radian) + scrll,
                positions[i].x + CLOCK_WIDTH * Math.cos(radian));
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < H.length; ++i) {
    setPosition($$('Hours')[i],
                positions[i].y + HAND_Y + (i * HAND_HEIGHT) * Math.sin(hrs) + scrll,
                positions[i].x + HAND_X + (i * HAND_WIDTH) * Math.cos(hrs));
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < M.length; ++i) {
    setPosition($$('Minutes')[i],
                positions[i].y + HAND_Y + (i * HAND_HEIGHT) * Math.sin(min) + scrll,
                positions[i].x + HAND_X + (i * HAND_WIDTH) * Math.cos(min));
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < S.length; ++i) {
    setPosition($$('Seconds')[i],
                positions[i].y + HAND_Y + (i * HAND_HEIGHT) * Math.sin(sec) + scrll,
                positions[i].x + HAND_X + (i * HAND_WIDTH) * Math.cos(sec));
  }
  updateYear(date, scrll);
  requestAnimationFrame(ClockAndAssign);
}

initialize();
}());
```

```css
.Face {
  position: absolute;
  height: 10;
  widdth: 10;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1em;
  color:;
}

.Hours {
  position: absolute;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  color:;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.Minutes {
  position: absolute;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  color:;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.Seconds {
  position: absolute;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  color:;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.Date {
  position: absolute;
  height: 10;
  width: 10;
  font-size: 1em;
  color:;
}
​
```

```html
    <div id="clock">
    <div id="Od" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Of" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Oh" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Om" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Os" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
​
```

問題箇所は、"function updateYear(currentDate, scrll) {}"内の下記の部分です。

```
    // Date wrapper
    var html = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < yearLength; ++i) {
      html += '<div class="Date">' + yearCharacters[i] + '</div>';
    }
    $('Od').children[0].innerHTML = html;


  if ( currentDate.getMinutes() % 2 == 0 ) {

      var divChildren = $('Od').children[0].children;
         for (var i = 0; i < divChildren; ++i) {
            var divEl = divChildren[i];

      if ((i >= 0) && (i < 2)) {
            divEl.children[0].style.color="red";

                         }
                  }
          }

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

質問で挙げられていた所を以下のように変更してみました。
変更点は2つ目のforの部分と色の設定の部分です。

forの部分では`i < divChildlen`を　`i < divChildlen.length`に変更しました

`divEl`に色の設定を行う部分では、`divEl`には子要素がないのでchildrenを使わなくても直接、色を設定することができます。

childrenについては下のリンクが参考になると思います。
[ParentNode.children - Web API インターフェイス | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children)

```
// Date wrapper
var html = '';
for (var i = 0; i < yearLength; ++i) {
  html += '<div class="Date">' + yearCharacters[i] + '</div>';
}
$('Od').children[0].innerHTML = html;


if ( currentDate.getMinutes() % 2 == 0 ) {

  var divChildren = $('Od').children[0].children;
     for (var i = 0; i < divChildren.length; i++) { //変更点1
        var divEl = divChildren[i]; 

  if ((i >= 0) && (i < 2)) {
        divEl.style.color="red"; //変更点2

                     }
              }
      }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
        body {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.Face {
  position: absolute;
  height: 10;
  widdth: 10;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #0000ff;
}

.Hours {
  position: absolute;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.Minutes {
  position: absolute;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.Seconds {
  position: absolute;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #ff0000;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.Date {
  position: absolute;
  height: 10;
  width: 10;
  font-size: 1em;
  color:;
}
    </style>
    </head>
<body>
    <div id="clock">
    <div id="Od" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Of" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Oh" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Om" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Os" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

(function(){
        "use strict";

function $(sel) {
  return document.getElementById(sel);
}

function $$(sel) {
  return document.getElementsByClassName(sel);
}

function setPosition(element, y, x) {
  element.style.top = y + 'px';
  element.style.left = x + 'px';
}

const CLOCK_HEIGHT = 40,
    CLOCK_WIDTH = 40,
    CLOCK_FROM_MOUSE_Y = 0,
    CLOCK_FROM_MOUSE_X = 100;

const H = '...'.split('');
const M = '....'.split('');
const S = '.....'.split('');
const SPEED = 0.6,
    FACES = '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12'.split(' ');
const HAND_HEIGHT = CLOCK_HEIGHT / 4.5;
const HAND_WIDTH = CLOCK_WIDTH / 4.5;
const HAND_Y = -7,
    HAND_X = -2.5,
    STEP = 0.06;

var ymouse = 0,
    xmouse = 0;
var currStep = 0;
var lastBasePositions = [];

function initialize() {
  for (var i = 0; i < FACES.length; ++i) {
    lastBasePositions[i] = {x:0, y:0};
  }

  var html = '';
  // Face wrapper
  html = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < FACES.length; ++i) {
    html += '<div class="Face">' + FACES[i] + '</div>';
  }
  $('Of').children[0].innerHTML = html;

  // Hours wrapper
  html = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < H.length; ++i) {
    html += '<div class="Hours">' + H[i] + '</div>';
  }
  $('Oh').children[0].innerHTML = html;

  // Minute wrapper
  html = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < M.length; ++i) {
    html += '<div class="Minutes">' + M[i] + '</div>';
  }
  $('Om').children[0].innerHTML = html;

  // Seconds wrapper
  html = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < S.length; ++i) {
    html += '<div class="Seconds">' + S[i] + '</div>';
  }
  $('Os').children[0].innerHTML = html;

  // Mouse move event handler
  document.onmousemove = function(evnt) {
    ymouse = evnt.clientY + CLOCK_FROM_MOUSE_Y;
    xmouse = evnt.clientX + CLOCK_FROM_MOUSE_X;
  };

  requestAnimationFrame(ClockAndAssign);
}

var lastYearPositions = [{x:0, y:0}];
var lastYearString = ' ';
var lastYearLocale = '';
function updateYear(currentDate, scrll) {
  var yearString = lastYearString;
  if (currentDate.getMinutes() % 2 == 0) {
    if (lastYearLocale != 'ja'){
      yearString = currentDate.toLocaleDateString("ja-JP-u-ca-japanese", { era: "long", year: "numeric" }).
          replace(/\u200e/g, "").replace(" ", "");
    lastYearLocale = 'ja';
          }
  } else {
    if (lastYearLocale != 'en'){
      yearString = currentDate.toLocaleDateString("en-US", { era: "long", year: "numeric" }).
          replace(/\u200e/g, "") + "年";
    lastYearLocale = 'en';
          }
  }

  var yearLength = lastYearPositions.length;
  if (yearString != lastYearString) {
    lastYearString = yearString;
    var yearCharacters = yearString.split('');
    yearLength = yearCharacters.length;

    // Date wrapper
    var html = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < yearLength; ++i) {
      html += '<div class="Date">' + yearCharacters[i] + '</div>';
    }
    $('Od').children[0].innerHTML = html;


  if ( currentDate.getMinutes() % 2 == 0 ) {

      var divChildren = $('Od').children[0].children;
         for (var i = 0; i < divChildren.length; i++) {
            var divEl = divChildren[i];

      if ((i >= 0) && (i < 2)) {
            divEl.style.color="red";

                         }
                  }
          }

  }
  var positions = [{}];
  var lastPosition = lastYearPositions[0];
  positions[0].y = lastPosition.y + ((ymouse) - lastPosition.y) * SPEED;
  positions[0].x = lastPosition.x + ((xmouse) - lastPosition.x) * SPEED;
  for (var i = 1; i < yearLength; ++i) {
    lastPosition = i < lastYearPositions.length ?
        lastYearPositions[i] :
        lastYearPositions[lastYearPositions.length - 1];
    positions[i] = {};
    positions[i].y = lastPosition.y + (positions[i-1].y - lastPosition.y) * SPEED;
    positions[i].x = lastPosition.x + (positions[i-1].x - lastPosition.x) * SPEED;
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < yearLength; ++i) {
    var radian = currStep + i * (360 / yearLength) * Math.PI / 180;
    setPosition($$('Date')[i],
                Math.round(positions[i].y) + CLOCK_HEIGHT * 1.5 * Math.sin(radian) + scrll,
                Math.round(positions[i].x) + CLOCK_WIDTH * 1.5 * Math.cos(radian));
  }
  lastYearPositions = positions;
  currStep -= STEP;
}

function ClockAndAssign() {
  var date = new Date();
  var secs = date.getSeconds();
  var sec = -1.57 + Math.PI * secs / 30;
  var mins = date.getMinutes();
  var min = -1.57 + Math.PI * mins / 30;
  var hr = date.getHours();
  var hrs = -1.575 + Math.PI * hr / 6 + Math.PI * parseInt(date.getMinutes(), 10) / 360;
  $('Od').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
  $('Of').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
  $('Oh').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
  $('Om').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
  $('Os').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
  var scrll = 0;

  var positions = [{}];
  var lastPosition = lastBasePositions[0];
  positions[0].y = Math.round(lastPosition.y + (ymouse - lastPosition.y) * SPEED);
  positions[0].x = Math.round(lastPosition.x + (xmouse - lastPosition.x) * SPEED);
  for (var i = 1; i < FACES.length; ++i) {
    lastPosition = lastBasePositions[i];
    positions[i] = {};
    positions[i].y = Math.round(lastPosition.y + (positions[i - 1].y - lastPosition.y) * SPEED);
    positions[i].x = Math.round(lastPosition.x + (positions[i - 1].x - lastPosition.x) * SPEED);
  }
  lastBasePositions = positions;

  var split = 360 / FACES.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < FACES.length; ++i) {
    var radian = -1.0471 + i * split * Math.PI / 180;
    setPosition($$('Face')[i],
                positions[i].y + CLOCK_HEIGHT * Math.sin(radian) + scrll,
                positions[i].x + CLOCK_WIDTH * Math.cos(radian));
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < H.length; ++i) {
    setPosition($$('Hours')[i],
                positions[i].y + HAND_Y + (i * HAND_HEIGHT) * Math.sin(hrs) + scrll,
                positions[i].x + HAND_X + (i * HAND_WIDTH) * Math.cos(hrs));
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < M.length; ++i) {
    setPosition($$('Minutes')[i],
                positions[i].y + HAND_Y + (i * HAND_HEIGHT) * Math.sin(min) + scrll,
                positions[i].x + HAND_X + (i * HAND_WIDTH) * Math.cos(min));
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < S.length; ++i) {
    setPosition($$('Seconds')[i],
                positions[i].y + HAND_Y + (i * HAND_HEIGHT) * Math.sin(sec) + scrll,
                positions[i].x + HAND_X + (i * HAND_WIDTH) * Math.cos(sec));
  }
  updateYear(date, scrll);
  requestAnimationFrame(ClockAndAssign);
}

initialize();
}());
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございました。変更点1は試したのですが、うまくいきませんでした。どこか微妙に間違っていたのかもしれません。

Answer (score 0):

年にクラスを割り当ててる箇所を以下のように修正。

```
    // Date wrapper
    var html = '';
    var is_heisei = yearString.match(/^平成.*/);
    for (var i = 0; i < yearLength; ++i) {
      var cls = 'Date';
      if (is_heisei && i < 2)
        cls += ' red';
      html += '<div class="' + cls + '">' + yearCharacters[i] + '</div>';
    }
    $('Od').children[0].innerHTML = html;
```

css に以下を追加。

```
.red {
  color: #ff0000;
}
```

以上でできてるようです。

```js
(function(){
        "use strict";

function $(sel) {
  return document.getElementById(sel);
}

function $$(sel) {
  return document.getElementsByClassName(sel);
}

function setPosition(element, y, x) {
  element.style.top = y + 'px';
  element.style.left = x + 'px';
}

const CLOCK_HEIGHT = 40,
    CLOCK_WIDTH = 40,
    CLOCK_FROM_MOUSE_Y = 0,
    CLOCK_FROM_MOUSE_X = 100;

const H = '...'.split('');
const M = '....'.split('');
const S = '.....'.split('');
const SPEED = 0.6,
    FACES = '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12'.split(' ');
const HAND_HEIGHT = CLOCK_HEIGHT / 4.5; 
const HAND_WIDTH = CLOCK_WIDTH / 4.5;
const HAND_Y = -7,
    HAND_X = -2.5,
    STEP = 0.06;

var ymouse = 0,
    xmouse = 0;
var currStep = 0;
var lastBasePositions = [];

function initialize() {
  for (var i = 0; i < FACES.length; ++i) {
    lastBasePositions[i] = {x:0, y:0};
  }

  var html = '';
  // Face wrapper
  html = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < FACES.length; ++i) {
    html += '<div class="Face">' + FACES[i] + '</div>';
  }
  $('Of').children[0].innerHTML = html;

  // Hours wrapper
  html = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < H.length; ++i) {
    html += '<div class="Hours">' + H[i] + '</div>';
  } 
  $('Oh').children[0].innerHTML = html;

  // Minute wrapper
  html = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < M.length; ++i) {
    html += '<div class="Minutes">' + M[i] + '</div>';
  }
  $('Om').children[0].innerHTML = html;

  // Seconds wrapper
  html = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < S.length; ++i) {
    html += '<div class="Seconds">' + S[i] + '</div>';
  }
  $('Os').children[0].innerHTML = html;

  // Mouse move event handler
  document.onmousemove = function(evnt) {
    ymouse = evnt.clientY + CLOCK_FROM_MOUSE_Y;
    xmouse = evnt.clientX + CLOCK_FROM_MOUSE_X;
  };

  requestAnimationFrame(ClockAndAssign);
}

var lastYearPositions = [{x:0, y:0}];
var lastYearString = ' ';
var lastYearLocale = '';
function updateYear(currentDate, scrll) {
  var yearString = lastYearString;
  if (currentDate.getMinutes() % 2 == 0) {
    if (lastYearLocale != 'ja'){
      yearString = currentDate.toLocaleDateString("ja-JP-u-ca-japanese", { era: "long", year: "numeric" }).
          replace(/\u200e/g, "").replace(" ", "");
    lastYearLocale = 'ja';
          }
  } else {
    if (lastYearLocale != 'en'){
      yearString = currentDate.toLocaleDateString("en-US", { era: "long", year: "numeric" }).
          replace(/\u200e/g, "") + "年";
    lastYearLocale = 'en';
          }
  }

  var yearLength = lastYearPositions.length;
  if (yearString != lastYearString) {
    lastYearString = yearString;        
    var yearCharacters = yearString.split('');
    yearLength = yearCharacters.length;

    // Date wrapper
    var html = '';
    var is_heisei = yearString.match(/^平成.*/);
    for (var i = 0; i < yearLength; ++i) {
      var cls = 'Date';
      if (is_heisei && i < 2)
        cls += ' red';
      html += '<div class="' + cls + '">' + yearCharacters[i] + '</div>';
    }
    $('Od').children[0].innerHTML = html;


  if ( currentDate.getMinutes() % 2 == 0 ) {

      var divChildren = $('Od').children[0].children;
         for (var i = 0; i < divChildren; ++i) {
            var divEl = divChildren[i];
               
      if ((i >= 0) && (i < 2)) {
            divEl.children[0].style.color="red";
                              
                         }
                  }
          }

  }
  var positions = [{}];
  var lastPosition = lastYearPositions[0];
  positions[0].y = lastPosition.y + ((ymouse) - lastPosition.y) * SPEED;
  positions[0].x = lastPosition.x + ((xmouse) - lastPosition.x) * SPEED;
  for (var i = 1; i < yearLength; ++i) {
    lastPosition = i < lastYearPositions.length ?
        lastYearPositions[i] :
        lastYearPositions[lastYearPositions.length - 1];
    positions[i] = {};
    positions[i].y = lastPosition.y + (positions[i-1].y - lastPosition.y) * SPEED;
    positions[i].x = lastPosition.x + (positions[i-1].x - lastPosition.x) * SPEED;
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < yearLength; ++i) {
    var radian = currStep + i * (360 / yearLength) * Math.PI / 180;
    setPosition($$('Date')[i],
                Math.round(positions[i].y) + CLOCK_HEIGHT * 1.5 * Math.sin(radian) + scrll,
                Math.round(positions[i].x) + CLOCK_WIDTH * 1.5 * Math.cos(radian));
  }
  lastYearPositions = positions;
  currStep -= STEP;
}

function ClockAndAssign() {
  var date = new Date();
  var secs = date.getSeconds();
  var sec = -1.57 + Math.PI * secs / 30;
  var mins = date.getMinutes();
  var min = -1.57 + Math.PI * mins / 30;
  var hr = date.getHours();
  var hrs = -1.575 + Math.PI * hr / 6 + Math.PI * parseInt(date.getMinutes(), 10) / 360;
  $('Od').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
  $('Of').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
  $('Oh').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
  $('Om').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
  $('Os').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
  var scrll = 0;

  var positions = [{}];
  var lastPosition = lastBasePositions[0];
  positions[0].y = Math.round(lastPosition.y + (ymouse - lastPosition.y) * SPEED);
  positions[0].x = Math.round(lastPosition.x + (xmouse - lastPosition.x) * SPEED);
  for (var i = 1; i < FACES.length; ++i) {
    lastPosition = lastBasePositions[i];
    positions[i] = {};
    positions[i].y = Math.round(lastPosition.y + (positions[i - 1].y - lastPosition.y) * SPEED);
    positions[i].x = Math.round(lastPosition.x + (positions[i - 1].x - lastPosition.x) * SPEED);
  }
  lastBasePositions = positions;

  var split = 360 / FACES.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < FACES.length; ++i) {
    var radian = -1.0471 + i * split * Math.PI / 180;
    setPosition($$('Face')[i],
                positions[i].y + CLOCK_HEIGHT * Math.sin(radian) + scrll,
                positions[i].x + CLOCK_WIDTH * Math.cos(radian));
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < H.length; ++i) {
    setPosition($$('Hours')[i],
                positions[i].y + HAND_Y + (i * HAND_HEIGHT) * Math.sin(hrs) + scrll,
                positions[i].x + HAND_X + (i * HAND_WIDTH) * Math.cos(hrs));
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < M.length; ++i) {
    setPosition($$('Minutes')[i],
                positions[i].y + HAND_Y + (i * HAND_HEIGHT) * Math.sin(min) + scrll,
                positions[i].x + HAND_X + (i * HAND_WIDTH) * Math.cos(min));
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < S.length; ++i) {
    setPosition($$('Seconds')[i],
                positions[i].y + HAND_Y + (i * HAND_HEIGHT) * Math.sin(sec) + scrll,
                positions[i].x + HAND_X + (i * HAND_WIDTH) * Math.cos(sec));
  }
  updateYear(date, scrll);
  requestAnimationFrame(ClockAndAssign);
}

initialize();
}());
```

```css
.Face {
  position: absolute;
  height: 10;
  widdth: 10;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1em;
  color:;
}

.Hours {
  position: absolute;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  color:;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.Minutes {
  position: absolute;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  color:;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.Seconds {
  position: absolute;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  color:;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.Date {
  position: absolute;
  height: 10;
  width: 10;
  font-size: 1em;
  color:;
}
  
.red {
  color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
    <div id="clock">
    <div id="Od" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Of" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Oh" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Om" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Os" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
​
```

Comment: 回答をありがとうございました。"$('Od').children[0].innerHTML = html;"以下は不要のようですね。下記のようにすれば、次期元号(２文字と仮定)に適用されるようです。    // Date wrapper
    var html = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < yearLength; ++i) {
      var cls = 'Date';
     if (( currentDate.getMinutes() % 2 == 0 )&&(i < 2))
        cls += ' red';
      html += '<div class="' + cls + '">' + yearCharacters[i] + '</div>';
    }
    $('Od').children[0].innerHTML = html;